# titlebar bottom

Tags: android, titlebar, custom-titlebar

i read this tutorial how to create a custom-titlebar.

http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/my-own-titlebar-backbutton-like-on-the-iphone-t4591.html

works fine BUT:

is it possible to add this bar not as a titlebar on the top but on the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own `TextView` and place it in an absolute position on a layout (see `AbsoluteLayout` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html)) but I would recommend against this as it breaks from the normal user interface standards and could be confusing to users. In addition if you have scrolling in your layout the positioning would become more complex. As far as I know there is no built-in way of moving the title bar.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea.
You can turn off the title bar and add something like title bar to the bottom of all your layouts:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:width="fill_parent"
   android:height="fill_parent">
   <LinearLayout 
      android:id="@+id/layout_container"
      android:weight="1"
      android:height="0dp"
      android:width="fill_parent">
      ...
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout 
      androdi:id="@+id/titlebar"
      android:height="wrap_content"
      android:width="fill_parent">
      ...
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But i've never seen a title bar at the bottom.